# BlockingQueue.size() returns wrong size in Publisher-Subscribers

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, publish-subscribe, blockingqueue

I have the problem regarding the implementation of One Publisher - Multiple Subscribers pattern. The Publisher uses the fixed-size buffer and queue the messages. The messages are send to all subscribers. The ordering of messages get by subscribers must be the same as the ordering of publishing messages.

I use BlockingQueue to hold publisher messages (*publisherQueue*) and pass them to each subscriber BlockingQueue (*subscriberQueue*).

The issue is that the buffer and subscribers are working correctly, but the buffer size (*publisherQueue.size()*) always returns 1.

```
System.out.println("Actual number of messages in buffer: " + publisherQueue.size());
```

Here is my full code:

*PublisherSubscriberService.java*

```
package program;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue;


public class PublisherSubscriberService {
    private int buffer;
    private int subscribersNumber;
    static Set<subscriber> subscribers = new HashSet<subscriber>();

    public PublisherSubscriberService(int buffer, int subscribersNumber) {
        this.buffer = buffer;
        this.subscribersNumber = subscribersNumber;
    }

    public void addsubscriber(subscriber subscriber) {
        subscribers.add(subscriber);
    }

    public void start() {
        publisher publisher = new publisher(buffer);
        System.out.println("publisher started the job");

        for (int i = 0; i < subscribersNumber; i++) {
            subscriber subscriber = new subscriber(buffer);
            subscriber.setName(Integer.toString(i + 1));
            subscribers.add(subscriber);
            new Thread(subscriber).start();
            System.out.println("Subscriber " + subscriber.getName() + " started the job");
        }
        new Thread(publisher).start();
    }

    public class Publisher implements Runnable {
        private int buffer;
        final BlockingQueue<Message> publisherQueue;

        public Publisher(int buffer) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            publisherQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(buffer);
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
                Message messageObject = new Message("" + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                    publisherQueue.put(messageObject);
                    System.out.println("Queued message no " +         messageObject.getMessage());
                    System.out.println("Actual number of messages in buffer:     " + publisherQueue.size());
                    for (subscriber subscriber : subscribers) {
                        subscriber.subscriberQueue.put(messageObject);
                    }
                    publisherQueue.take();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    System.out.println("Some error");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    class Subscriber implements Runnable {
        private String name;
        private int buffer;
        final BlockingQueue<Message> subscriberQueue;

        public Subscriber(int buffer) {
            this.buffer = buffer;
            subscriberQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>(buffer);
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Message messageObject;
                while (true) {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    messageObject = subscriberQueue.take();
                    System.out.println(this.getName() + " got message: " + messageObject.getMessage());
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Some error");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
class Message {
    private String message;

    public Message(String str) {
        this.message = str;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

}
}
```

*PublisherSubscriberProgram.java*

```
    package program;

public class ProducerConsumerProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProducerConsumerService service = new ProducerConsumerService(10, 3);
        service.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your publisher never has more than 1 item in the queue. Each time through your loop you put and take a single item:

```
                **publisherQueue.put(messageObject);**
                System.out.println("Queued message no " +         messageObject.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Actual number of messages in buffer:     " + publisherQueue.size());
                for (subscriber subscriber : subscribers) {
                    subscriber.subscriberQueue.put(messageObject);
                }
                **publisherQueue.take();**
```

With the code you have provided, there is point in even having the publisher queue.